# Error: the templates_c directory does not exist or is not writable

Tags: apache, templates, authorization, smarty, writable

When launching my web application on local EasyPHP web server, I am still getting this :
Error: the templates_c directory does not exist or is not writable
Please make sure that the templates_c directory does exist in the root directory of the generated application and it is writable by the web server user.

Please help me what to do to solve this problem. Best regards.

I try windows sharing authorizations but don't work. Expecting file/folder read/write authorizations manager to be installed on local EasyPHP Devserver.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create template_c directory inside you project if it not present.It is required to store compiled template and try to launch.